# Jmeter POST API with json body

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

I am novice with Jmeter and I want to POST this body

```
{
   "key": {
      "hash": "599ba25a0d7c7d671bee93172ca7e272fc87f0c0e02e44df9e9436819067ea28",
      "hashAlgo": "SHA256"
   },
   "event": {
      "name": "TEST_CHAINCODE_4",
      "timestamp": "2020-04-23T16:10:00Z",
      "appId": "DATAROOM",
      "userId": "RKA",
      "metadata": {},
      "manifest": "ZGZoc2RlaGpzcnRoamRyZXRocmVzaGpkcmZzaGpkcmVoanJzaA=="
   }
}
```

But I have this error

> {
> "type" : "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
> "title" : "Bad Request",
> "status" : 400,
> "detail" : "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@607e653e; line: 1, column: 3]",
> "path" : "/api/2.0/data",
> "message" : "error.http.400"
> }

In my header manager I added this headers:
[image]

Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where exactly the problem is without seeing your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration, but my crystal ball suggests checking the state of `Use multipart/form-data` checkbox

[image]

It **must not be ticked**

In general [HTTP Status 400 means "Bad request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) so something is definitely wrong with your request URL, headers or body